# Hadoop MapReduce Program for removing duplicate records

Tags: hadoop

Could anyone help me to write the mapper and reducer for merging these two files and then removing the duplicate records?

These are the two text files:

```
file1.txt
2012-3-1a
2012-3-2b
2012-3-3c
2012-3-4d
2012-3-5a
2012-3-6b
2012-3-7c
2012-3-3c
```

and file2.txt:

```
2012-3-1b
2012-3-2a
2012-3-3b
2012-3-4d
2012-3-5a
2012-3-6c
2012-3-7d
2012-3-3c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple word count program will do the job for you. The only change you need to make is, set the output value of the Reducer as NullWritable.get()

Answer (score 0):

Is there a common key in both the files which helps identify if record matched or not? If so then:
Mappers Input: Standard TextInputFormat
Mapper's Output Key : Common Key and Mapper's output Value : Entire Record.
At reducer : It will  not be required to iterate over the Keys just take only 1 instance of the Value for Write.

If the match or duplicacy can be concluded only if complete record matched: then
Mappers Input: Standard TextInputFormat
Mapper's Output Key : Entire Record and Mapper's output Value : NullWritable.
At reducer: It will not be required to iterate over the Keys. Just take only one instance of Key and write that as a Value.
Reducer Output Key: Reducer Input Key, Reducer Output Value : NullWritable

Comment: I am only given the above two text files and instructed to write programs in java for mapper and reducer and compile the program, but I don't know how to do that. there is no common key .

Comment: In that case, go with the 2nd option as I said in previous comment:       If the match or duplicacy can be concluded only if complete record matched: then Mappers Input: Standard TextInputFormat Mapper's Output Key : Entire Record and Mapper's output Value : NullWritable. At reducer: It will not be required to iterate over the Keys. Just take only one instance of Key and write that as a Value. Reducer Output Key: Reducer Input Key, Reducer Output Value : NullWritable

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to remove duplicate lines in large text data, which uses hash for efficiency:

DRMapper.java

```java
    import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    
    class DRMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    
      private Text hashKey = new Text();
      private Text mappedValue = new Text();
    
      @Override
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();

          hashKey.set(Hashing.murmur3_32().hashString(line, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString());
          mappedValue.set(line);
          context.write(hashKey, mappedValue);

      }
    
    }
```

DRReducer.java

```java
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class DRReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
      @Override
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Text value;
        if (values.iterator().hasNext()) {
          value = values.iterator().next();
          if (!(value.toString().isEmpty())) {
            context.write(value, NullWritable.get());
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

DuplicateRemover.java

```java
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
    
    
    public class DuplicateRemover {
      private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_REDUCERS = 210;
    
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: DuplicateRemover <input path> <output path>");
          System.exit(-1);
        }
    
   
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(DuplicateRemover.class);
        job.setJobName("Duplicate Remover");
    
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
        job.setMapperClass(DRMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DRReducer.class);
    
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    
        job.setNumReduceTasks(DEFAULT_NUM_REDUCERS);
    
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
    }
```

compile with:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 -cp $(hadoop classpath) *.java
jar cf dr.jar *.class
```

Assuming that the input text files are in in_folder, run as:

```
hadoop jar dr.jar in_folder out_folder
```